# How to compile multiple sound files into one sound file, based on order of individual sounds in array?

Tags: android, audio, media-player

In my application, I have two lists of sounds from different categories and a playlist. The user of the app must select sounds from either list and create a custom sound sequence. When they are satisfied with the order of this final "playlist" (the list that they created from the other two), they should be able to compile the array of sound files into one sound file. I am looking for the easiest solution to this. After looking at ffmpeg, I am hoping that there is something built into the Android platform that will allow me to do this.

NOTE: I am not talking about simple playback. I am talking about actually compiling multiple sound files into one sound file.

If anyone has a useful suggestion, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to use the .WAV format's "CUE" feature - Have one big file containing all the sounds with a cue for each one.  After the user selects the sounds to play, append a Playlist chunk with the correct cues to the big file.  The file will be 2x as big as it needs to be, but it avoids the alternative, which is to manually stitch together the PCM data and write a brand new file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The size probably won't be such a problem. Now, does this create one file?

Comment: Yes, both the CUE chunk and the Playlist get embedded in the original WAV file.  A decent WAV editor should let you add the cues, and you would append the playlist programatically.

Comment: Sorry, but may you clarify one more thing. With respect to android, do you know if this is possible?

Comment: It's cerainly possible to edit the WAV files with standard file editing techniques.  The format is not that complicated.  I don't know if there is an android audio player which will pay attention to the playlist chunk or not.